# How can we change the complete code of Junit to Testng?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, testng

I have written the code in Junit, I want to change into TestNg coz i need automatic reports which i can't do it on Junit. I have seen some answers related to this type of question but as i m a fresher, i couldn't understand them easily. Please anyone help me in easy way with step by step process. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately this site wont get you a step by step process .. try something post it and people will improve that .

Comment: Most build systems that support JUnit produce an XML output file that can be used to produce a report. Some continuous integration systems even parse these XML files to provide a pretty web-based UI showing the results of a test run

Answer (score 1):

Refer below URL, testng provide a way to do same as you needed :-

```
http://testng.org/doc/migrating.html
```

Another thing you can do but I never tried anyone of that

```
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_run_junit_tests.htm
```

You can also do it manually if your code is not so big

testng and junit both using java code, they just have different framework and annotation. Do one thing copy your code from JUNIT and paste it in testng class with add annotation according to testng like @@BeforeSuite